# SQL What is the Total Payments Done Year To Date by Month

Tags: sql, count, formula, payment

I am attempting to answer this question: What is the Total Payments Done Year To Date by Month?

I am needing a count and a sum - how many payments were done in a month, and what is the total of the payments done in each month (in one year's span (2023)).

My current code is:

```
SELECT trip_id, id, user_id, date (created_at), storage_currency, converted_subtotal,     subtotal, converted_total, total, 
SUM(converted_total) OVER (Partition by year(created_at) order by  created_at
            ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and current row) as YTD_Frame
FROM production.payments`
        
--where created_at >= '2023-01-01 and status !='failed'
```

My current date is

| Created_at | Currency | Converted_Subt | subtotal |  | converted_total | Total | YTD_Frame |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | USD | 20000 | 200.00 | 20600 | 206.00 | 206000 |  |
| 2018-01-01 | USD | 40000 | 400.00 | 41000 | 410.00 | 48000 |  |
| 2018-01-02 | USD | 34000 | 340.00 | 34200 | 342.00 | 82000 |  |
| 2018-01-02 | USD | 45000 | 450.00 | 44000 | 440.00 | 64000 |  |
| 2018-02-01 | USD | 50000 | 500.00 | 50500 | 505.00 | 164000 |  |
| 2019-02-01 | USD | 142000 | 1420.00 | 142000 | 1420.00 | 112000 |  |
| 2019-01-18 | USD | 80000 | 800.00 | 80700 | 807.00 | 238200 |  |
| 2019-03-20 | USD | 225000 | 2250.00 | 226000 | 2260.00 | 421400 |  |
| 2020-01-01 | USD | 205000 | 2050.00 | 205000 | 2050.00 | 716600 |  |
| 2020-01-01 | USD | 150000 | 1500.00 | 152000 | 1520.00 | 1329000 |  |
| 2021-01-01 | USD | 74000 | 740.00 | 74000 | 740.00 | 231900 |  |
| 2021-01-01 | USD | 50000 | 500.00 | 50000 | 500.00 | 94200 |  |
| 2021-01-01 | USD | 40000 | 400.00 | 40000 | 400.00 | 198300 |  |
| 2022-01-01 | USD | 75000 | 750.00 | 75200 | 752.00 | 997700 |  |
| 2022-01-01 | USD | 125000 | 1250.00 | 125000 | 1250.00 | 802000 |  |
| 2023-01-01 | USD | 82000 | 820.00 | 82000 | 820.00 | 781400 |  |
| 2023-06-04 | USD | 90000 | 900.00 | 90000 | 900.00 | 909200 |  |
| 2023-11-10 | USD | 105000 | 1050.00 | 105000 | 1050.00 | 899300 |  |

My desired outcome would look like:

| Month | Payment Count | Payment Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | 240 | 304,874 |
| February | 262 | 423,971 |
| March | 281 | 238,761 |
| April | 207 | 348,112 |
| May | 298 | 403,171 |
| June | 240 | 304,874 |
| July | 262 | 436,001 |
| August | 282 | 241,891 |
| September | 214 | 347,123 |
| October | 301 | 307,174 |

Comment: Which dbms is this for???  That's one of the most important information to give.

Comment: It is for IOMETE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which RDBMS you're dealing with, but for MySQL, try this:

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M') as Month, COUNT(*) as Payment_Count, SUM( converted_total) as Payment_Total
FROM production.payments
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2024-01-01' AND and status != 'failed'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M')